# Use firebase onSnapshot() in for loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

The below code works for getting my data from firestore. I'm trying to update this to use `onSnapshot()` instead of of `get()`. Maybe the core of my confusion is `onSnapshot()` doesn't return a promise and I've tried just adding the listeners into an array but it seems the data doesn't get updated. How do I iterate over a `for` loop of `onSnapshot()`'s and render the results?

```
const [activityDataArray, setActivityDataArray] = useState([]);
const userActivityIds = userData.activities

useEffect(() => {
    let promises = [];
    for (const activityId of userActivityIds) {
        promises.push(getFirestoreData("activities", activityId));
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(response => setActivityDataArray(response));
}, [userActivityIds]);
```

---

UPDATED CODE:
When I `console.log()` the array it has my data, but I think this is a trick with chrome dev tools showing new information. I think when I call `setActivityDataArray` it's running it on an empty array and then it never gets called again. So the data doesn't render unless I switch to a different tab in my application and go back. Then it renders correctly (so I know the data is good, it's just a rendering issue). I think I need to re-render within `onSnapshot()` but how do I do this correctly?

```
const [activityDataArray, setActivityDataArray] = useState<any>([]);
const userActivityIds: string[] = userData.activities

useEffect(() => {
    let activityDataArrayDummy: any[] = []
    for (const i in userActivityIds) {
        firebase.firestore().collection("activities").doc(userActivityIds[i])
            .onSnapshot((doc) => {
                activityDataArrayDummy[i] = doc.data();
            });
    }
    console.log("activityDataArrayDummy", activityDataArrayDummy)
    setActivityDataArray(activityDataArrayDummy);
}, [userActivityIds]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply calling `onSnapshot()` in a loop should do it.

```
import { doc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

for (const activityId of userActivityIds) {
  // get reference to document
  const docRef = doc(db, "activities", activityId)
  
  onSnapshot(docRef, (snapshot) => {
    // read and render data from snapshot
  })
}
```

However, if you ever need to unsubscribe from any of the listeners then you might have to store the [`Unsubscribe`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.unsubscribe.md#unsubscribe_interface) function returned by [`onSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#onsnapshot)
somewhere in state.

---

Just in case you have 10 or less items in `userActivityIds` then you can use `onSnapshot()` with a `Query` instead:

```
const q = query(collection(db, "activities"), where(documentId(), "in", userActivityIds));

onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
  // ... 
})
```

Comment: So I'm kinda doing that. I have `setActivityDataArray([...activityDataArray, doc.data()])` in the loop, but it's overwriting each other.. ie. only the last one is getting rendered

Comment: @esafresa yes so all `onSnapshot()` would run independent of each other. It might be best to push data from these in an array and then pass it to `setActivityDataArray` so the state it updated only once and not for every snapshot. Can you try doing so by adding an array right before for loop?

Comment: first off i really appreciate your help :) can you elaborate on what you mean? I think I need to call `setActivityDataArray` from within `onSnapshot` (ie. `onNext`) or else it wont render data updates, correct? I'm now trying `setActivityDataArray({...activityDataArray, ...copiedActivityObj})`, ie `{...prevState, ...newObj}` but I think this doesn't work in react, objects are overwriting eachother

Comment: I got it. I see what you mean now. Thank you! :D

Comment: Ah wait... this is buggy. I think I need to call setState within onSnapshot's onNext or it doesn't render. Suggestions?

Comment: @esafresa what I meant was you can declare an array before the for loop starts, then push the document in that array. Once you have all documents, the use setState.. can you share your updated code?

Comment: Okay added updated code :)

Comment: @esafresa can you try the code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/DharmarajX24/01d337a9e3fc87566361ae0bf4979161)? I'll update that here if that's what you are looking for .

Answer (score 0):

I went with this. Apparently state in react isn't guaranteed to be updated, so the proper way to setState with updated data is using a callback function.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

```
const [activityDataObj, setActivityDataObj] = useState({})
const userActivityIds: string[] = userData.activities

useEffect(() => {
    for (const i in userActivityIds) {
        firebase.firestore().collection("activities").doc(userActivityIds[i])
            .onSnapshot((doc) => {
                setActivityDataObj((activityDataObj) => {
                    return {...activityDataObj, [userActivityIds[i]]: doc.data()}
                })
            });
    }
}, [userActivityIds]);
```